# Error after closing file explorer

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I created a pretty good working vba code for importing a csv file from the windows file explorer. However, when I close the explorer before I open a file, a 1004 error dialog pops up. It says the text file to refresh the external range can't be found. The line line at the bottom should be the cause:

> **.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False**

Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of this error?

```
Dim ClickCount As Integer

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim begin As String
Dim myInput As Long

ClickCount = ClickCount + 1

If ClickCount > 1 Then GoTo Line1 Else GoTo Line2

Line1:
myInput = MsgBox("Gebruikers zijn reeds geimporteerd. Records worden mogelijk dubbel opgeslagen. Wilt u toch doorgaan met importeren?", vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Import error")
    If myInput = vbYes Then
    GoTo Line2
    Else
    Exit Sub

Line2:

Set sht = ActiveSheet

  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
begin = "$A" & "$" & LastRow + 1

Dim fileName
  fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv")

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & fileName, _
        Destination:=range(begin))
        .Name = "User import 1.0"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would be nice to see the part of the VBA where you import the file. There you should add a check so you don't use an `ActiveSheet` that points to null when you select nothing.

Comment: Is `fileName` the full path or just the name of the file?  If it's just the name then that might fail if your current directory changes.

Comment: @Alfabravo Thanks for your comment. I just pasted the whole code which I use to import the file below my question. I hope this is enough to give you a better understanding. What kind of check do you mean? I think the problem could be that my ActiveSheet currently points to null when I don't select a file.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your comment. fileName is the full path. But currently I don't have any issues with importing the csv files. The problem is that I get an error when I close the file explorer before choosing a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim fileName
fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv")

If fileName = False then Exit Sub
```